# Hibernate Many to Many doesn't save changes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities Category and Community which is related to each other by Many To Many annotation, i can retrieve data from my db (postgres) but i can't save changes, when i call merge method on Hibernate entity manager, nothing heppens.

This is Category entity

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(name = "category_community", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "community_id", referencedColumnName = "id") )
private List<Community> communities;
```

This is Community entity mapping

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "communities", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
private List<Category> categories;
```

and when i do like this

```
Community community = communityService.getById(id);
community.setCategories(newCategories);
entityManager.marge(community);
```

changes don't persist in db

persistance.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="ecclUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/datasources/EcclDS</jta-data-source>
    <jar-file>lib/eccl-common.jar</jar-file>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true"  /> 

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Have you persisted it before? It's entityManager.merge(community). Did you try it with entityManager.flush() afterwards?

Comment: flush does not help, yes i persisted it early but after rebuild of my project (maybe when hibernate session changed) changed rows dissapeared

Comment: Can you update your answer with the persistence.xml? The create-drop could be the reason.

Comment: i found the solution, i just inverted association, now when Community is owner of association all fine, problem was present because i was trying to merge Community which wasn't owner.